# Xamarin android and date picker

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Is date picker much more complicated in Android than in Windows phone, an easy code in windows is this. (A date picker and a textBox)

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.datePicker1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler<DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs>
            (datePicker1_ValueChanged);
        DateTime MyVal = DateTime.Today;
       textBlock1.Text = MyVal.AddDays(35).ToShortDateString();

    }

    private void datePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)e.NewDateTime;
        this.textBlock1.Text = date.AddDays(35).ToShortDateString();

    }
```

if You use Xamarin could you use the C# code or have you go with Java code. Which is the easiest way ?

Answer (score 2):

axml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/date_EditText" />
```

activity.cs

```
    [Activity(Label = "YourApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnDateSetListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var dateEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.date_EditText);
        dateEditText.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        dateEditText.Click += delegate
        {
            OnClickDateEditText();
        };
    }

    private void OnClickDateEditText()
    {
        var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, dateTimeNow.Year, dateTimeNow.Month, dateTimeNow.Day);
        datePicker.Show();
    }

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.date_EditText).Text = new DateTime(year, month, dayOfMonth).ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is date picker much more complicated in Android than in Windows phone

If you simply want to show the `DatePicker` in android a couple of Xml codes will be enough:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If you want to have the equivalent of `datePicker1.ValueChanged` in android. Then you need to create a new class, which implements `DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener`:

```
public class DatePickerChangeHandler : DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then use it in `DatePicker.init()`:

```
datePicker.Init(2017, 1, 30, new DatePickerChangeHandler());
```

> if You use Xamarin could you use the C# code or have you go with Java code

If you use Xamarin, C# will be your development language.

Answer (score 0):

May it's too late, But if anyone wants to do this easily in C# xamarin android, You can use DatePicckerDialog, so you don't need to add a date picker to your axml,

```
         DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        today = today.AddDays(2);
        DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, OnDateSet, today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day);
        dateDialog.DatePicker.MinDate = today.Milliseconds;
```

And use this on the click event of the edit text,

```
txtPrefDate.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dateDialog.Show();
        };
```